# In which scriptures that Hindu Number counting system is completely written?

Tags: puranas, vishnu-purana, numbers, vayupurana

A photo of [Hindu Number Counting System](https://photos.app.goo.gl/ouQVqFd2kPQ6zXG98) is higher than described in [4-5 Shloka, 3rd Chapter of 6th Part of Vishnu Purana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp158.htm#fn_1614) same also described in **Vayu Purana**:

> [image: Hindu Number Counting System]

Is there any scripture (Vedas/Upanishads/Puranas) which tells more higher counting system or its last?

**Note** : Please don't answer from Wikipedia.

Comment: @YDS Thank you so much for editing. Actually, I am new user on site and how to use and put your question. I don't know?So Thanks

Comment: no problem.... welcome to Hinduism SE!!!